# Invariance of Maxwell equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, maxwell-equations

Is there an easy way to show that the Maxwell equations
$$
\partial_\alpha F_{\beta\gamma} + \partial_\gamma F_{\alpha\beta} + \partial_\beta F_{\gamma\alpha} = 0
$$
are invariant under a Lorentz transformation:

$$\overline x^\mu = \Lambda^\mu_{\phantom\mu\nu}x^\nu$$

$$\overline F^{\mu\nu} = \Lambda^\mu_{\phantom\mu\alpha}\Lambda^\nu_{\phantom\nu\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}$$

Unfortunately my lecture notes are incomplete and I haven't found any other source.

A straightforward attack does not help. I think there are some tricks necessary. I am searching for a proof which only uses the transformations rules. Nothing more... (please without the Hodge star operator)

Comment: *"A straightforward attack does not help."* Uh, why not? You can pull the Lorentz trafo matrices through the derivative since they're constant, and then just cancel them (by multiplying with their inverses, since the RHS is zero and will stay zero). This equation is already what one would call "manifestly Lorentz covariant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ACuriousMind said in a comment above, such an equation is manifestly covariant. Suppose the homogeneous Maxwell equations hold in the Lorentz transformed coordinates, i.e. that
$$\bar\partial_\alpha \bar F_{\beta\gamma} + \bar\partial_\gamma \bar F_{\alpha\beta} + \bar \partial_\beta \bar F_{\gamma\alpha} = 0$$
Lorentz transformation are global and thus the representation is constant. Thus we may pull the matrices out from under the derivatives. Then we have
$$\Lambda_\alpha{}^\mu\Lambda_\beta{}^\nu\Lambda_\gamma{}^\rho \partial_\mu F_{\nu\rho}+\text{cyclic permutations}=0$$
Lorentz transformations are invertible, so now multiply by the three inverse matrices to obtain
$$\partial_\mu F_{\nu\rho}+\text{cyclic permutations}=0$$ 
which shows that the equation is Lorentz covariant.

Comment: Ah, I see. So one needs to know that $\Lambda_\alpha^{\phantom \alpha \beta} = (\Lambda^{-1})^\beta_{\phantom\beta\alpha}$ right? This directly follows from $\eta^{-1}=\Lambda\eta^{-1}\Lambda^T$ right?

Comment: @thyme Yes, that looks correct.